# Problem with @Transactional : The transaction is not active

Tags: quarkus-panache

I was playing around with Quarkus when I encountered a problem. I created a test method with `@Transactional` that takes some time to respond. However, in the middle of processing, I encountered an error: "**Caused by: jakarta.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016102: The transaction is not active! Uid is 0:ffff0a050012:df43:658ecbaf:0.**"

It seems like the transaction is being dropped while the response is still processing.

Here is a sample code to reproduce the error:

```java
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Transactional
public String test() throws Exception {

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    Test test = new Test();
    test.name = "xxx";
    test.persist();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        test = new Test();
        test.name = "xxx";
        test.persist();
    }

    return "ok";
}
```

The execution of this method never ends because of a Quarkus `RollbackException` being thrown with "The transaction is not active" error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: After some search, it seems like the underlying problem is the transaction being  timeout. A simple workaround is to use the annotation @TransactionConfiguration(timeout = 10000)